# SharePoint REST API - Fetching folders from subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

I am new to using SharePoint online REST API's. I started with basics by connecting to SharePoint online via Postman and list folders in a subsite. So I have achieved the first step of connecting to SharePoint online via Postman by getting the access token. I am confused as to how to list folders inside a subsite.

So this is my site structure:

```
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/OM/Customer Invoicing
```

Here OM is the subsite and Customer Invoicing is the document library.

I want to construct the API URL to access the folders inside Customer Invoicing document library using a GET request.

I tried this:

```
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27OM/Customer Invoicing')/Files
```

But I think I am doing it wrongly as I need to fetch folders from the document library in a subsite.

Comment: Check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/61488378-f218-4eef-981e-0dbb8c027d9e/show-documents-from-all-the-subsite-in-a-table-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify Rest endpoint like this:

```
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/OM/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/OM/Customer Invoicing')/Folders
```

"OM/Customer Invoice" in GetFolderServerRelativeUrl needs to prepend "/" like "/OM/Customer Invoice":

[image]

Comment: Didn’t work. Why are you adding OM twice?

Comment: OM is necessary to necessary to get sub site document library when working with GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl. Did the library name is "Customer Invoicing" really ? I tested the same endpoint in my side, it works as expected.